# cx_Freeze won't work with pygame (already tried "import pygame._view")

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze, python-3.3

I'm trying to use the following setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
exe = Executable(
script="stars.pyw",
)

setup(
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

To build the following Pygame example:

```
import random, math, pygame
import pygame._view
from pygame.locals import *

#constants
WINSIZE = [640, 480]
WINCENTER = [320, 240]
NUMSTARS = 150


def init_star():
    "creates new star values"
    dir = random.randrange(100000)
    velmult = random.random()*.6+.4
    vel = [math.sin(dir) * velmult, math.cos(dir) * velmult]
    return vel, WINCENTER[:]


def initialize_stars():
    "creates a new starfield"
    stars = []
    for x in range(NUMSTARS):
        star = init_star()
        vel, pos = star
        steps = random.randint(0, WINCENTER[0])
        pos[0] = pos[0] + (vel[0] * steps)
        pos[1] = pos[1] + (vel[1] * steps)
        vel[0] = vel[0] * (steps * .09)
        vel[1] = vel[1] * (steps * .09)
        stars.append(star)
    move_stars(stars)
    return stars


def draw_stars(surface, stars, color):
    "used to draw (and clear) the stars"
    for vel, pos in stars:
        pos = (int(pos[0]), int(pos[1]))
        surface.set_at(pos, color)


def move_stars(stars):
    "animate the star values"
    for vel, pos in stars:
        pos[0] = pos[0] + vel[0]
        pos[1] = pos[1] + vel[1]
        if not 0 <= pos[0] <= WINSIZE[0] or not 0 <= pos[1] <= WINSIZE[1]:
            vel[:], pos[:] = init_star()
        else:
            vel[0] = vel[0] * 1.05
            vel[1] = vel[1] * 1.05


def main():
    "This is the starfield code"
    #create our starfield
    random.seed()
    stars = initialize_stars()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    #initialize and prepare screen
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINSIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Stars')
    white = 255, 240, 200
    black = 20, 20, 40
    screen.fill(black)

    #main game loop
    done = 0
    while not done:
        draw_stars(screen, stars, black)
        move_stars(stars)
        draw_stars(screen, stars, white)
        pygame.display.update()
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT or (e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_ESCAPE):
                done = 1
                break
            elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and e.button == 1:
                WINCENTER[:] = list(e.pos)
        clock.tick(50)


# if python says run, then we should run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It's important to say I'm using a Pygame unoffical release: **pygame-1.9.2pre.win-amd64-py3.3.‌exe**

But the script works just fine before compiling.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work: what did you try, and what happened?

Comment: When I compile it using "python setup.py build" the build software (stars.exe) won't open. I'm using Python 3.3, Pygame 1.9.2 and cx_freeze 4.3.1, all x64, by the way.

Comment: OK, and when it won't open, do you get any kind of error message? If you're running it by double clicking, try running it from the command line, because sometimes the window closes before you can see the error.

Comment: This is the error I get when trying to open "stars.exe": http://pastebin.com/7YMg2gGj

Comment: Drat, that error again. That's come up occasionally, but it hasn't been fixed yet. Stick an `import re` in your script, and freeze it again.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you, Thomas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

That's an error we see occasionally, but haven't got round to fixing yet. You can work around it by adding a line to the script:

```
import re
```